How I can send FIL in filecoin network
My network: filecoin.
I use this RPC: https://api.node.glif.io
I try send FIL token from A to B address on filecoin network and I got error:
{
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  error: {
    code: 1,
    message: "verify msg failed: message will not be included in a block: 'GasLimit' field cannot be less than the cost of storing a message on chain 745262 < 747863"
  },
  id: 1
}

code:
const tx = {
        to: (receiver+"").toLowerCase(),
        value: Utils.parseEther(ethers.utils.formatEther(1+"")+""),
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(745262),
        maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.hexlify(txGasPrice),
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.hexlify(txGasPrice-1),
        nonce: await getTransactionCount(rpcUrl, (await wallet.getAddress()).toLowerCase()),
        type: 2,
        chainId: await getChainId(rpcUrl),
    };

const rawTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
        const response = await sendRawTransaction(rpcUrl, rawTransaction);

function "sendRawTransaction" code:
async function sendRawTransaction(rpcUrl, signedTx) {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    const dataString = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", "params": ["'+ signedTx +'"], "id":1}';

    const options = {
        url: rpcUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString,
    };

    var result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let json = response.body;
            let obj = JSON.parse(json)
            console.log(obj);
            
            resolve(obj.result)
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        }
    }));
    
    return await result;
}

I try increase gasLimit but same problem...
another variables values:
maxFeePerGas 72858108
maxPriorityFeePerGas 72858107

full tx values:
{
  to: '0xcc1947438463a878e576cdc19fa1c78ed1e48ce1',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasLimit: '0x0b5f2e',
  maxFeePerGas: '0x0457b9fc',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x0457b9fb',
  nonce: 0,
  type: 2,
  chainId: 314
}

maybe sameone know where is bug?
Thank you, God bless you!

This issue is resolved by increasing the "gasLimit" value to 1723354, which allows the FIL to transfer.
